# How do I simplify $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n + 1} + \sqrt{n}\right)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

how to simplify $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n + 1} + \sqrt{n}\right)}$$

---

I already multiplied by the conjugate but I'm not going anywhere

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n + 1} + \sqrt{n}\right)} *\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}$$

and i will have someting like,

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n}\ (\sqrt{n + 1} + \sqrt{n}) * \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}} $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please let us know your efforts so that we can better help you.

Comment: Is this fraction a term of a series?

Comment: yes it is @RobertZ im having some trouble with them

Comment: @JonatanIaczinski it is telescopic: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n + 1} + \sqrt{n}\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$

Comment: 3*2−1 = 5... 3·(2−1) = 3... "someting" ≠ "something"... Put in much more effort into your work, if you want to learn.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Observe that: $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}= \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}$